# How does jQuery.ajax({url:'foo.js', dataType:'script', async:false}) differ from document.write?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was hoping to use `$.ajax({url:'foo.js', async:false, dataType:'script'})` to block content display until foo.js had loaded.  The assumption was that synchronous script loading is roughly equivalent to `document.write`.  I'm guessing that's incorrect since I still get FOUC.

While I can solve the immediate issue by hiding the element and showing it on script load, I'm curious how the synchronous `$.ajax` call differs from `document.write`.  If you happen to know a way to get content blocking behavior from jQuery, that would be interesting also.

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You could define a variable/construct in foo.js, and wait for its definition.

The .load() function can be used to wait on a certain element's load: http://api.jquery.com/load/